# Sharing Tiled Maps

Tags: 2d, tilemap, tiled

Where can share my existing [Tiled](http://www.mapeditor.org/) maps, as well as download and use other people's existing maps?

Comment: I don't think such a website would be useful because maps are usually designed for one specific game.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question is not about game development.

Comment: Not about game develop? How might you develop a tile-based game without a tile map? I think such a website would be just as useful as http://opengameart.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't come across anything like that yet. But you could check GitHub for games that use Tiled. Then you can download their Tiled files and images. Here's one such repository: https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/tree/master/examples

Additionally, you can also do Google searches by filetype and look for .tmx files. You might have to do a lot of searching through all those results. But you might find some good stuff along the way. Type this into Google's search box: `filetype:tmx tileset`

None of the methods listed above allow you to share your own work, however.

Comment: This answer is pretty much it, though I don't agree with the last statement because you can of course share your own work on github or on your own site that would eventually be indexed by Google.

Comment: That's true that anyone can share their own work individually. What I'm hoping to find, though, is a centralized hub where you can share and find specific maps. Maybe that's a project I'll have to start myself...